403 when trying to view PDF
In have a site on HostGator.
The site has many pdf files in a "pdf" folder with several sub directories.
The problem is all the pdf's are showing a 403 error and fail to load.
To attemnpt to resolve the issue, I created a .htaccess file as follows...


<FilesMatch "(?i).*\.(pdf)$" >
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>



... and placed it in the "pdf" directory.
However, I'm still getting 403 errors.
I'm new to .htaccess coding but found the above code in this post. text
Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Maybe the webserver isn't allowed to read the files, due to file system permissions? What does the error log have to say?

Instead of trying random snippets you find on the internet you need to find the reason why you receive back a 403. First stop should be your http server's error log file. That is where you can read the reason. Most likely your settings (or the hosters settings) have disabled access to that folder. That is where you need to start. With that information we's probably be able to help.
